# Does Desura accept Paypal payments?

Tags: desura

I'm reading through the EULA of Desura to better understand the system and the deal it offers, and there's an entire section dedicated to credit card information and chargebacks; now I'm pretty sure this is also repeated in the Steam EULA, but it did make me wonder - does Desura accept PayPal payments?

Otherwise, it's pretty much a deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; they currently accept PayPal, Visa and Mastercard. These options are displayed to you at the checkout screen.

[image: Desura payment methods]